# Azure Synapse /ADF Dataflow Timeout

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a dataflow that add a column to a dataset.
Everything was working fine for a long time, but now i run into a timeout error every time.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GHvF.png)

Dataset is pretty small (less than 20 lines)

I saw that my source (API from an application - Copy Activity) have a new column since the error, Copy activity works fine tho.

[Dataflow Activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Ccy.png)

I tried adding a bigger working cluster.
Scratching and redoing mappings into the dataflow to add the new data from the source.

Thing is, if i do a debug in the dataflow, and try to preview data, each step works correctly.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: What is the Timeout setting on the Dataflow Activity in the pipeline?

Comment: Initially was 12 hours, modified to 15 minutes for the debug tests. Activity usually took 5 Mins to run when it was working

Comment: Increase the value and check

Comment: Increase a value to 12+ hours to add a column into a 20 lines dataset ? Seems like a costly solution !